# SQL Server Express 2005 unicode characters

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I'm working with an SQL Server 2005 Express instance. Any attempt (both programatically or by using a table editor (for example VS Server Explorer --> Edit Table Data)) to enter a unicode string results in a sequence of question marks (????). I guess that either SQL Server 2005 Express doesn't support unicode at all or it requires some extra configuration to enable unicode. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

THe datatype must be `nvarchar` (*note the n at the start*) and you must use the N prefix when using strings ..

```
INSERT INTO <table> (somefield) VALUES (N'string to insert..')
```

- [Microsoft technote](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530)
- [nchar and nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Not all Unicode characters may be rendered correctly by the font you chose in your editor.